# Drawing dot mesh on 3dplot

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

**DISCLAIMER:** this seems like a bug. If you know where I should post this (message board, forum, bug tracker...) please let me know.

I have a relatively simple image consisting of 2 parametric 3d plots which are drawn in a rotated coordinate system.

```
\pstThreeDCoor[Beta=15,Alpha=80]%
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](0,90)(-1,3){
u arctan 180 add 3.141592 mul 180 div t cos mul
u arctan 180 add 3.141592 mul 180 div t sin mul
u neg 2 add
}%
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](-1,3)(0,90){
t arctan 180 add 3.141592 mul 180 div u cos mul
t arctan 180 add 3.141592 mul 180 div u sin mul
t neg 2 add
}%
\psset{dotstyle=*,dotscale=2,DrawCoor=true}%
\pstThreeDDot(2.356,0.000,3)%
\pstThreeDDot(3.142,0.000,2)%
\pstThreeDDot(3.927,0.000,1)%
\pstThreeDDot(4.249,0.000,0)%
\pstThreeDDot(4.391,0.000,-1)%
\pstThreeDDot(2.177,0.902,3)%
\pstThreeDDot(2.902,1.202,2)%
\pstThreeDDot(3.628,1.503,1)%
\pstThreeDDot(3.925,1.626,0)%
\pstThreeDDot(4.056,1.680,-1)%
\pstThreeDDot(1.666,1.666,3)%
% shortened for brevity
```

I wanted to add a dot on each node of the wireframe so I used LO Calc to pull out the coordinates of every dot. When I add the dots (`pstThreeDDot`) the coordinate system transformation (`Alpha, Beta`) is reset which offsets all the dots as seen in the following capture

[image: dot matrix offseted to original 3d coords away from wireframe]

I tried to reorder each part only to find out that the `pstThreeDDot`s cause a reset of the coordinate system and are completely immune to it

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple workaround which is to `psset` it before doing anything

```
\psset{Beta=15,Alpha=80}%
```

I used to think that setting these values in `pstThreeDCoor` was enough to make it affect al subsequent elements in the current environment. Alas, it's not true for `pstThreeDDot`s

I'm still curious as to why this behaviour exists, and if it is a bug and there is a bug tracker please let me know

## EDIT

the mailing list can be found at  [mailto:pstricks@tug.org](http://mailto:pstricks@tug.org)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot,pst-math}
\begin{document}

\psset{Beta=15,Alpha=80}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pstThreeDCoor[xMax=7,yMax=5]
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](0,90)(-1,3){
    u ATAN Pi add t cos mul
    u ATAN Pi add t sin mul
    u neg 2 add
}%
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](-1,3)(0,90){
    t ATAN Pi add u cos mul
    t ATAN Pi add u sin mul
    t neg 2 add
}%
\psset{dotstyle=*,dotscale=2,drawCoor=true}%
\pstThreeDDot(2.356,0.000,3)
\pstThreeDDot(3.142,0.000,2)
\pstThreeDDot(3.927,0.000,1)
\pstThreeDDot(4.249,0.000,0)
\pstThreeDDot(4.391,0.000,-1)
\pstThreeDDot(2.177,0.902,3)
\pstThreeDDot(2.902,1.202,2)
\pstThreeDDot(3.628,1.503,1)
\pstThreeDDot(3.925,1.626,0)
\pstThreeDDot(4.056,1.680,-1)
\pstThreeDDot(1.666,1.666,3)
% shortened for brevity 
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pstThreeDCoor[xMax=7,yMax=5]
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](0,90)(-1,3){
    u ATAN Pi add t cos mul
    u ATAN Pi add t sin mul
    u neg 2 add
}%
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=curve,yPlotpoints=5](-1,3)(0,90){
    t ATAN Pi add u cos mul
    t ATAN Pi add u sin mul
    t neg 2 add
}%
\parametricplotThreeD[plotstyle=dots,dotscale=2,drawCoor,
  xPlotpoints=5,yPlotpoints=5](0,90)(-1,3){
    u ATAN Pi add t cos mul
    u ATAN Pi add t sin mul
    u neg 2 add
}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]